# How can I convert a method to a class?

Tags: c#, class

I'm trying to change my methods to a class. I did that but some of the work is not happening:

What is the right way to pass in `(object sender, EventArgs e)`?

This is the code to use the method:

```
public void GetPlayerChoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    { 
        ChangeProperties(sender, e);
        PlayerWon();
    }
```

This is the method:

```
    //Change the properties of the buttond and cheack who's turn is it.
    public void ChangeProperties(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var btn = sender as Button;

            if (playerX.Turn == true)
            {
                btn.Text = playerX.Name;
                btn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 15, 0);
                playerX.Turn = false;
                playerO.Turn = true;
                buttonUser1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 156, 53);
                buttonUser2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            }

            else
            {
                btn.Text = playerO.Name;
                btn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(96, 255, 40);
                playerX.Turn = true;
                playerO.Turn = false;
                buttonUser1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
                buttonUser2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 156, 53);
            }
            btn.Enabled = false;
        }
        //Cheack if there is a winer. 
        public void PlayerWon()
        {
            if ((button1.Text == button2.Text && button2.Text == button3.Text) ||  //horizontal
                 (button4.Text == button5.Text && button5.Text == button6.Text) || //horizontal
                 (button7.Text == button8.Text && button8.Text == button9.Text) || //horizontal
                 (button1.Text == button4.Text && button4.Text == button7.Text) || //vertical
                 (button2.Text == button5.Text && button5.Text == button8.Text) || //vertical
                 (button3.Text == button6.Text && button6.Text == button9.Text) || //vertical
                 (button1.Text == button5.Text && button5.Text == button9.Text) || //slanted
                 (button3.Text == button5.Text && button5.Text == button7.Text))   //slanted
            {
                EnableAllButtonFalse();

                if (playerX.Turn == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("O is the winner");
                    playerO.Score += 1;
                }
                if (playerX.Turn == false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("X is the winner");
                    playerX.Score += 1;
                }
                NewGame();
            }
        }
        //Enable false all button in the game.
        public void EnableAllButtonFalse()
        {
            foreach (Control c in Controls)
            {
                if (c is Button)
                {
                    c.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }

        //Enable true all button in the game.
        public void EnableAllButtonTrue()
        {
            foreach (Control c in Controls)
            {
                if (c is Button)
                {
                    c.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        public void NewGame()
        {
        EnableAllButtonTrue();

        if(playerX.Turn == false)
            {
                playerX.Turn = true;
                playerO.Turn = false;
            }
        else
            {
                playerX.Turn = false;
                playerO.Turn = true;
            }
        }
```

When I changed my program to use the methods it didn't worked proper.
It did only some of the code. I can't understand why it's happening.

This is the code to use the class:

```
public void GetPlayerChoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExtensionMethods ex = new ExtensionMethods();
        ex.Sender = sender;
        ex.E = e;
        ex.ChangeProperties(sender, e);
        ex.PlayerWon();
    }
```

This is the class:

```
    class  ExtensionMethods : Form1
    {
    private object sender;
    private EventArgs e;

    public object Sender { get; set; }
    public EventArgs E { get; set; }


    //Change the properties of the buttond and cheack who's turn is it.
    public void ChangeProperties(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var btn = sender as Button;

            if (playerX.Turn == true)
            {
                btn.Text = playerX.Name;
                btn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 15, 0);
                playerX.Turn = false;
                playerO.Turn = true;
                buttonUser1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 156, 53);
                buttonUser2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
            }

            else
            {
                btn.Text = playerO.Name;
                btn.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(96, 255, 40);
                playerX.Turn = true;
                playerO.Turn = false;
                buttonUser1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
                buttonUser2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 156, 53);
            }
            btn.Enabled = false;
        }
        //Cheack if there is a winer. 
        public void PlayerWon()
        {
            if ((button1.Text == button2.Text && button2.Text == button3.Text) ||  //horizontal
                 (button4.Text == button5.Text && button5.Text == button6.Text) || //horizontal
                 (button7.Text == button8.Text && button8.Text == button9.Text) || //horizontal
                 (button1.Text == button4.Text && button4.Text == button7.Text) || //vertical
                 (button2.Text == button5.Text && button5.Text == button8.Text) || //vertical
                 (button3.Text == button6.Text && button6.Text == button9.Text) || //vertical
                 (button1.Text == button5.Text && button5.Text == button9.Text) || //slanted
                 (button3.Text == button5.Text && button5.Text == button7.Text))   //slanted
            {
                EnableAllButtonFalse();

                if (playerX.Turn == true)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("O is the winner");
                    playerO.Score += 1;
                }
                if (playerX.Turn == false)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("X is the winner");
                    playerX.Score += 1;
                }
                NewGame();
            }
        }
        //Enable false all button in the game.
        public void EnableAllButtonFalse()
        {
            foreach (Control c in Controls)
            {
                if (c is Button)
                {
                    c.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }

        //Enable true all button in the game.
        public void EnableAllButtonTrue()
        {
            foreach (Control c in Controls)
            {
                if (c is Button)
                {
                    c.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        public void NewGame()
        {
        EnableAllButtonTrue();

        if(playerX.Turn == false)
            {
                playerX.Turn = true;
                playerO.Turn = false;
            }
        else
            {
                playerX.Turn = false;
                playerO.Turn = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is this homework/an assignment? If so, your lecturer/tutor is probably wanting you to simplify your program by splitting sections into their own methods.

Comment: that's a lot of code, and hard to see where the problem is based on your question.  "some stuff works, some stuff doesn't", be specific to help us help you.

Comment: What is the right way to pass in the sender?

Comment: What is the right way to pass in (object sender, EventArgs e)?

Comment: Note: `void Whatever(object sender, EventArgs e)` is a typical event handler signature. Event handlers are not called directly, but registered to an event. Event handlers shouldn't be public. They should always be private (e.g. Resharper would complain otherwise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your code and was able to get it to work. [Here is a .NETFiddle of it working](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FUsiAd).

Here is the code.

```
using System;

public class  ExtensionMethods 
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ExtensionMethods em = new ExtensionMethods();
        em.PlayerWon();
    }

    public void PlayerWon()
    {
        NewGame();

    }

    public void NewGame()
    {
        Console.Write("Starting New Game");
    }
}
```

To use the sender, you will want to do something like this:

```
void HandleMyButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this method can have some arguments, if needed
    DoButtonWork();
}
```